# Fitting data vs. transforming data in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In [scikit-learn](http://www.astroml.org/sklearn_tutorial/general_concepts.html), all estimators have a `fit()` method, and depending on whether they are supervised or unsupervised, they also have a `predict()` or `transform()` method.

I am in the process of writing a [transformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.TransformerMixin.html) for an unsupervised learning task and was wondering if there is a rule of thumb where to put which kind of learning logic. The official documentation is not very helpful in this regard:

> `fit_transform(X, y=None, **fit_params)`
>   Fit to data, then transform it.

In this context, what is meant by both *fitting data* and *transforming data*?

Comment: Is it true that "depending on whether they are supervised or unsupervised, they also have a predict() or transform() method". Is that stated in docs somewhere? Seems that most models have both methods.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Fitting finds the internal parameters of a model that will be used to transform data. Transforming  applies the parameters to data. You may fit a model to one set of data, and then transform it on a completely different set.

For example, you fit a linear model to data to get a slope and intercept. Then you use those parameters to transform (i.e., map) new or existing values of `x` to `y`.

`fit_transform` is just doing both steps to the same data.

A scikit example: You fit data to find the principal components. Then you transform your data to see how it maps onto these components:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=2)

X = [[1,2],[2,4],[1,3]]

pca.fit(X)

# This is the model to map data
pca.components_

array([[ 0.47185791,  0.88167459],
       [-0.88167459,  0.47185791]], dtype=float32)

# Now we actually map the data
pca.transform(X)

array([[-1.03896057, -0.17796634],
       [ 1.19624651, -0.11592512],
       [-0.15728599,  0.29389156]])

# Or we can do both "at once"
pca.fit_transform(X)

array([[-1.03896058, -0.1779664 ],
       [ 1.19624662, -0.11592512],
       [-0.15728603,  0.29389152]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Wait, then what's the difference between transform and predict?

Comment: Let's use `PLSRegression` as an example. It has both `transform` and `predict` methods.

`predict(X)` applies the learned model to `X`, and returns `y_pred`. 
`transform(X)` applies dimensionality reduction to `X`, and returns `X_reduced`. 
`transform(X, y)` returns both `X_reduced` and `y_pred`

Comment: Thanks!  I couldn't find what you just plainly stated in any braod scikit-learn documentation.

Comment: I agree, the documentation is less than clear. Glad it helped.

Comment: So does that mean you can use transform() to predict?

Comment: Can you please provide me the same example of Linear Regression as you have provided the example of PCA?

Answer (score 8):

As other answers explain it, `fit` **does not need to be doing anything** (except from returning the transformer object). It is there so that all transformers have the same interface and work nicely with stuff like pipelines.
Of course some transformers need a `fit` method (think tf-idf, PCA...) that actually does things.
The `transform` method needs to return the transformed data.

`fit_transform` is a convenience method that chains the fit and transform operations. You can get it for free (!) by deriving your custom transformer class from `TransformerMixin` and implementing `fit` and `transform`.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, calling the `fit` method does not do anything. As you can see in [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html), not all transformers need to actually do something with `fit` or `transform` methods. My guess is that every class in scikit-learn should implement the fit, transform and/or predict in order for it to be consistent with the rest of the package. But I guess this is indeed quite an overkill.